# how to have nested lists in Lua

Tags: list, lua

I am trying to solve this problem from the 99 lisp problems

> Flatten a nested list structure.
> Transform a list, possibly holding lists as elements into a `flat' list by replacing each list with its elements (recursively).
> Example:

```
(my-flatten '(a (b (c d) e)))  
(A B C D E)
```

> Hint: Use the predefined functions list and append.

Problem is, I don't know how to create that nested list to begin with so I can try to flatten it myself. Please help thankyou

Answer (score 1):

In Lua "a list possibly holding lists as elements" is just a table possibly holding tables as elements.

From the Lua manual:

> Tables can be heterogeneous; that is, they can contain values of all
> types (except nil).
>
> ...
>
> Like indices, the values of table fields can be of any type

That of course includes tables.

The most trivial case is `local t = {{}}` or for the mentioned example (a (b (c d) e)) `local t = {a, {b, {c, d}, e}}`

Assuming a,b,c,d and e are strings your list would look like so:

```
local t = {"a", {"b", {"c", "d"}, "e"}
```

Comment: Most probably, the OP needs `{"a", {"b", {"c", "d"}, "e"}}`, trying to reproduced LISP atoms as strings.

Comment: @lhf well I assumed that a,b,c,d,e are non-nil values, but you're right that's most likely